# How to make ESP32 based, MQTT to AWS connected device stable and avoid locked in states on device

Tags: c++, mqtt, esp32, aws-iot

I am constructing ESP32 based devices for a variety of purposes, e.g. simple sensors (temperature etc.) and actors (relay controlling).
All of them base on a couple of examples found online that I combined and taylored for my purpose.

What all have in common is:

- ESP32 WROOM dev boards as basis
- Development with platformio in vs code and arduino framework
- core libraries:

  - Arduino
  - WiFiClientSecure
  - MQTTClient
  - ArduinoJson
  - WiFi
  - time
- publishing to AWS IoT Core every 5-60s with one topic per device "xxxx/000x/pub"
- power supply: 5v cellphone charger

What is the problem:

After a while (sometimes an hour, sometimes 2 weeks, I can't figure out a pattern) I don't receive messages in IoT Core anymore, although in serial port the "print" statements are done correctly. Those are part of the loop as is the message handling.
Also, I can't restart the devices via MQTT message if they are in that state, so I have to push the reset button manually.

What is my problem:

I want to build a simple, but reliable solution. Unfortunately, I do not know how to debug such a case, especially as I can't have the devices plugged in for serial analysis for days and weeks.
I read about "last will" and "testament", but I am not sure how to use those properly or if it even helps.

Below, I put the basic structure of my code with some comments. This is the sceleton that I use for the descirbed cases:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <secret.h> //change
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <MQTTClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "time.h"


#define AWS_IOT_PUBLISH_TOPIC   "topic/pub" //change
#define AWS_IOT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC "topic/sub" //change


const byte relay_gpio = 16; // the relay
const char* ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org"; // timeserver
const long  gmtOffset_sec = 3600; 
const int   daylightOffset_sec = 3600;
int relayState = 0;

String IoTID = "IoTID";
String sensorID = "IoTID_1"; //change

WiFiClientSecure net = WiFiClientSecure();
MQTTClient client = MQTTClient(1024);

void messageHandler(String &topic, String &payload)
{
  Serial.println("alive");
  // deserialize json
  StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
  deserializeJson(doc, payload);
  String message = doc["message"];
  Serial.println(message);
  if (message == "restart"){
    ESP.restart();
  }
  if (message == "remote_on"){
    digitalWrite(relay_gpio, HIGH);  
  }
  if (message == "remote_off"){
    digitalWrite(relay_gpio, LOW);
  }
}

void connectAWS()
{
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.println("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
 
  // Configure WiFiClientSecure to use the AWS IoT device credentials
  net.setCACert(AWS_CERT_CA);
  net.setCertificate(AWS_CERT_CRT);
  net.setPrivateKey(AWS_CERT_PRIVATE);
 
  // Connect to the MQTT broker on the AWS endpoint we defined earlier
  client.begin(AWS_IOT_ENDPOINT, 8883, net);
 
  // Create a message handler
  client.onMessage(messageHandler);
  
  Serial.println("Connecting to AWS IOT");
 
  while (!client.connect(THINGNAME))
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(100);
  }
 
  if (!client.connected())
  {
    Serial.println("AWS IoT Timeout!");
    return;
  }
 
  // Subscribe to a topic
  client.setCleanSession(false); // That's one thing that was recommended
  client.subscribe(AWS_IOT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC);
  //client.setOptions(60, false, 2000); // I tried some of those, but with either none or negative effects

  Serial.println("AWS IoT Connected!");
}

void publishMessage()
{
StaticJsonDocument<256> doc;

doc["IoTID"] = IoTID;

JsonObject meta_0 = doc["meta"].createNestedObject();
meta_0["SensorID"] = sensorID;
meta_0["key"] = "XX";
meta_0["latitude"] = 12.345;
meta_0["longitude"] = 67.890;
meta_0["LocName"] = "Somewhere";
meta_0["TimeCET"] = time(NULL);

JsonObject data_0 = doc["data"].createNestedObject();
data_0["switch_state"] = relayState;
char jsonBuffer[512];
serializeJson(doc, jsonBuffer);
 
client.publish(AWS_IOT_PUBLISH_TOPIC, jsonBuffer);
}


//

void setup() {
  pinMode(relay_gpio, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer);
  connectAWS(); //always connects. so far so good
}

void loop() {

  
  client.loop();  // Putting this
  delay(10);   // and this at the beginning of the loop improved stability and was recommended
  relayState  = digitalRead(relay_gpio);

  if (!client.connected()){
    client.connect(THINGNAME);
    client.loop();
  }

  client.onMessage(messageHandler);
  

  if (isnan(relayState)) {
    Serial.println("measurement error - waiting");
    delay(5000);
    ESP.restart();
  }

  lwmqtt_err_t lastError(); // for serial debugging
  lwmqtt_return_code_t returnCode();  // for serial debugging


  Serial.print(F("relayState: "));
  Serial.print(relayState);
  Serial.print(F(", Timestamp:"));
  Serial.println(time(NULL));
  if(time(NULL) > 1e9){ //make sure connection to timeserver is established
    publishMessage();
  }
  delay(5000);
  
}
```

Things I tried so far:

- Switching from PubSubClient.h to MQTTClient.h: Better
- Adding a 10ms delay after client.loop()
- Resizing of JSON buffers
- testing different loop delays (feels like: the shorter the better)
- adding a "auto restart after 22h" function (no improvment)
- adding a "restart via MQTT message" function (only working, if not already in locked-in state)

Comment: Have you tried adding an `else` block to the `if(time(NULL) > 1e9)` section to check that the time is still right and `publishMessage()` is actually called?

Comment: Hi and thanks, I added the time feature later in the process to have a origin side timestamp available on AWS. The described behaviour happend already before that. But you have a good point, as I could use that function to add some troublehandling code.